# loading external scala scripts into a scala file

Tags: scala, package, python-import

i originally made scripts with many functions on 2 individual scala worksheets. i got them working and now want to tie these individual scripts together by importing and using them into a third file. from what i have read you can not simply import external scripts you must first make them into a class and put them into a package. so i tried that but i still couldn't import it

i know this may be a bit basic for this site but im struggling to find much scala documentation.

i think my problem might span from a missunderstanding of how packages work. the picture below might help.

[my program example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R2Mm.png)

adder.scala

```
package adder
class adder {
  def add_to_this(AA:Int):Int={
    var BB = AA + 1;
    return BB
    }  
}
```

build.scala

```
package builder
class build {
  def make_numbers(){
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;}
}
```

main.sc

```
import adder
import builder 
object main {
 adder.adder.add_to_this(10);

}
```

the errors i get are

object  is not a member of package adder
object  is not a member of package builder

Answer (score 0):

Classes in scala slightly differ from classes in java. If you need something like singleton, you'll want to use `object` instead of class i.e.:

```scala
package com.example
object Main extends App {
  object Hide{
    object Adder{
      def addToThis(AA:Int):Int = AA + 1
    } 
  }
 object Example{
   import com.example.Main.Hide.Adder
   def run(): Unit = println(Adder.addToThis(10))
 }
 Example.run()
}
```

Consider objects like packages/modules which are also regular values. You can import an object by its full path, i.e. `com.example.Main.Hide.Adder` you can also import contents of an object by adding `.{addToThis}`, or import anything from object by adding `._` after an object.

Note that classes, traits and case classes could not be used as objects, you can't do anything with it unless you have an instance - there are no `static` modifier.